# C# Create Shortcut Icon Location is not working for network paths

Tags: c#, icons, shortcut

I'm using IwishRuntime Library to create shortcuts dynamically. Setting Icon location won't work if the icon is in a network path.

For Example if the path is something like "\\ServerName\Folder\Resources\Userguide.ico"; the icon won't be set. 
This happens only in windows 8 and 8.1. It works fine in prior operating systems.

Is there any workaround to fix this.

```
            string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Upgrade\Resources\userguide.ico";
            //Icon Location is set only if the file is there. If the file is not accessible due to security reasons 
            //Icon location is not set. The default program will be taken as the icon in this case.
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                shortcut.IconLocation = path;
            }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your network path should start with two slashes ("\\ServerName\Folder...") or is that a typo? Otherwise it could be a permission thing. Try placing a random text file in the same directory and reading it.

Comment: No it was a typo. It starts with \\ServerName. In fact it reads from the Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(). So it returns the correct value. There's no permission issue as well. I checked that. It doesn't work for network paths which starts with '\\'. Even for my own machine if I give the path as a network path - \\Tharindu\Share\Resources\userguide.ico it won't work. But If I give the path as D:\\...etc it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an @ in front of your Path and everytime \\

```
@"\\Network\\ExampleFolder"
```

Its working on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, Win10 creators edition. Conclusion was, Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon() will not run from a network path.. It won't read  the icon from the .ico file, my test...

```
        Icon myImage;
        string fn = sIconPath + "\\" + cSymbolIconFile;
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(fn)) myImage = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fn); 
              else MessageBox.Show("Error: File not found.");
        } catch(Exception EE) { MessageBox.Show("Error: "+EE.Message); }
```

When my sIconPath is a network path, I get an exception saying **"Error: Value of  is not valid for 'filePath'"**

Now to solve this, you should put the icon file in a Resource and include it in your link.

1. Create a Resource in a project "mydll" named e.g. "buttonresources", put your icon files into it ..
2. Put mydll.dll in the references of your executable main project
3. There should be a buttonresources.resx in your project now. Address an icon named e.g. "myicon" as follows..

   ```
       System.Reflection.Assembly a1 = GetType().Assembly;
       var m = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("mydll.buttonresources", a1);
       Icon myImage = (System.Drawing.Icon)m.GetObject("myicon");
   ```